# Shopify does not redirect to admin page after installation

Tags: shopify-app

I'm currently building a private app for Shopify. I've successfully passed the authorization step and get an appropriate response for it.
However, unlike other apps that I've seen, I'm not redirected to the Shopify's admin panel followed by my response page in the frame.
Instead, the redirection happens directly to my ngrok-generated address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to load your app within the Shopify admin then you can implement the [Embedded App SDK](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk/initialization).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Worked like a charm.